# Make 2 buttons inside a table cell be next to each other

Tags: html, css, button, html-table

I have the following code :

```
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="r.changeView('requests/edit/' + request.id)">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="r.changeView('requests/edit/' + request.id)">
          <i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
```

They appear on 2 different lines.

How can I make them appear next to each other on the same line ?

I tried a few things with `float` and `display` but without success.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or something for this? Would make it easier. 
Otherwise try to display: inline or inline-block in css

Comment: Is that twitter bootstrap ? if yes then what about a [Button group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If I add that code in a snippet the buttons are next to each other, so it's hard to reproduce:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="r.changeView('requests/edit/' + request.id)">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Button1
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="r.changeView('requests/edit/' + request.id)">
        <i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>Button2
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The buttons are already displayed as `inline-block`.
Maybe the table isn't wide enough; if so, You could try `<td style='white-space: nowrap'>`.

Comment: `<td style='white-space: nowrap'>` made it happen, thanks. However, the table is supposed to be wide enough since it's dynamicly resized depending on its content (I'm using smart-table). Not sure what causes this though

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Bootstrap, try using classes like "pull-left". This will float both of the buttons left and bring them inline. Also check to be sure nothing is overriding the current display attribute.

```
<div class="pull-left">...</div>
<div class="pull-right">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried `display: inline-block;`?
However that seems unnecessary because two buttons in the same table cell will appear on the same line.

```css
table,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>Button1</button>
      <button>Button2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is just css display inline code, which can be use to format your button
`form {
    display: inline;
}`

this displays an element as an inline element like span

Answer (score 1):

Please see how to use `<table>` tag inside in `<td>` and get all button in line.

```html
<table>
        <td>
           <table>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Add</button>
                    </td>
                   <td> 
                      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</button>
                  </td>
                  <td> 
                      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View</button>
                  </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
        </td>
 </table>
```

Comment: _shiver_ I don't think this is smart at all. Using tables to layout is already generally seen as ancient practice. Tables should only be for tabular content, and you defenitely should not use an extra table inside your table to layout content inside.